# TLSv1.2 Java 1.6 Bouncy Castle and RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, bouncycastle, resttemplate, java-6

I'm using restTemplate to connect me to other service and the application use Java 1.6_101 and Spring 3.2.18, is a legacy application, and you know what java 1.6 don't have support to TLSv1.2, now I configured Bouncy Castle to support TLSv1.2 and I installed JCE (Java Security Extension) for set the limit Key size in unlimited. Now the connection when are in the HandShake step fail.

Here the configuration code of the restTemplate, this agree all certificates.

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 20000;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestTemplateConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        try {

            Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

            Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 2);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    if (chain == null || chain.length < 1 || authType == null || authType.length() < 1) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }

                    String subject = chain[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
                    LOGGER.info("Auto-trusted server certificate chain for: " + subject);
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    //necesary
                }
            };


            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, new SecureRandom());

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"}, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                    .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                    .setConnectionTimeToLive(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("No se pudo inicializar configuracion SSL ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I use this class for call an API rest

> restTemplate.postForObject("https://someapi", request, some.class);

get the follow exceptions:

```
Iniciando llamado get token<{grant_type=client_credentials},{Content-Type=[application/json], Authorization=[Basic 516060891508785571340:H5DNTFwshoyCLGo4hc_c55S2AFO2oqxGq71BDulu3mJb]}>
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies]:122 - CookieSpec selected: default
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache]:76 - Auth cache not set in the context
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager]:249 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager]:282 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec]:234 - Opening connection {s}->https://api:443
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator]:131 - Connecting to api/zz.123.xxx.yyy:443
[07/12/2017 15:43:48] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:335 - Connecting socket to api/zz.123.xxx.yyy:443 with timeout 0
[07/12/2017 15:43:49] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:388 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1]
[07/12/2017 15:43:49] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:389 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
[07/12/2017 15:43:49] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:393 - Starting handshake
Dec 7, 2017 3:45:16 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient notifyAlertRaised
INFO: Client raised fatal(2) handshake_failure(40) alert: Failed to read record
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketWrap.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:82)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:327)
    at net.technisys.fiftech.service.PaymentsService.init(PaymentsService.java:69)
    at net.technisys.fiftech.controller.PaymentsController.init(PaymentsController.java:38)
    at net.technisys.mobile.techbank.bankinghandlers.ConsolidadaFalabellaHandler.obtenerProductos(ConsolidadaFalabellaHandler.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.SessionExpirationControl.doFilter(SessionExpirationControl.java:115)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.NextTransactionFilter.doFilter(NextTransactionFilter.java:90)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.MessageTypeBasedFilter.doFilter(MessageTypeBasedFilter.java:191)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.BuilderHeadersResponseFilter.doFilter(BuilderHeadersResponseFilter.java:52)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:186)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.BufferFlusherFilter.doFilter(BufferFlusherFilter.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.mdc.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at net.technisys.security.filters.ControlUserFilter.doFilter(ControlUserFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
[07/12/2017 15:45:16] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection]:87 - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
[07/12/2017 15:45:16] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec]:128 - Connection discarded
[07/12/2017 15:45:16] [DEBUG] [JSID=O-wySB2_4juRqnhzhF4y26EwhYLKB6uT5jMJ19l2oDyHAern33Tt!-2023087022!1512672075199] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection]:79 - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
```

Comment: Best approach: check the server log(s) or ask the server operator(s) to find out what the problem is. Next best: use www.ssllabs.com (if server is public on port 443) or some similar tool like nmap otherwise to find out what options and variations of TLS the server accepts. Then change either your app or the server so they agree.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I checked the configuration of both servers and one of them had port 443 closed.